# Rewriting the standard classes with xparse

Tags: sectioning, xparse

I practised with `xparse`. I rewrote the definition of `\part`. When I try the following code everything works:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{spart}% makes hyperref work

\makeatletter
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\part}{s m o}%
 {\cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{plain}%
  \if@twocolumn%
   \onecolumn%
   \@tempswatrue%
  \else%
   \@tempswafalse%
  \fi%
  \null\vfil%
 \IfNoValueTF{#3}%
  {\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\m@part*{#2}{#2}}{\m@part{#2}{#2}}}%
  {\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\m@part*{#2}{#3}}{\m@part{#2}{#3}}}}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\m@part}{s m m}%
 {\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\refstepcounter{spart}% makes hyperref work
               \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#3}}%
                {\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax%
                \refstepcounter{part}%
                \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#3}%
              \else%
                \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#3}%
              \fi}%
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering%
     \interlinepenalty \@M%
    \normalfont%
  \IfBooleanF{#1}{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax%
              \huge\bfseries \partname~\thepart%
              \par%
              \vskip 20\p@%
              \fi}%
 \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
\@endpart}
 \makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Teil 1}
\Blinddocument
\part*{Teil 2}
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Look at my \m@part macro. Firt I tried to call it \@part as it is called in book.cls. But when I compile this there are some errors. Example:

```
Use of \@part doesn't match its Definition.
```

or

```
Too many }'s.
```

I do not understand the problem. Why does it work with `\m@part` but not with `\@part`?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Most probably the issue is that `hyperref` redefines `\@part`

Comment: Thanks. You are right. When I delete \usepackage{hyperref} it works without any error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `hyperref` redefines `\@part`, essentially for doing what you do yourself with the `spart` counter.

You don't need to use two macros, anyway. I wouldn't change the syntax of part: the optional argument should go before the mandatory one.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\part}{s O{#3} m}{%
  \cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{plain}%
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
   \@tempswafalse
  \fi
  \null\vfil
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {% * version
    \csname phantomsection\endcsname % for hyperref
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#2}%
   }
   {% standard version
    \ifnum\c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#2}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#2}%
    \fi
   }%
  \markboth{}{}%
  {% print the title
   \centering \interlinepenalty\@M \normalfont
   \IfBooleanF{#1}
    {% standard version
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname~\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
    }%
   \Huge \bfseries #2\par
  }%
  \@endpart
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Teil 1}
\part[Ops 2]{Teil 2}
\part*{Teil 3}
\part*[Ops 4]{Teil 4}

\end{document}
```

Note that you need the most recent version of `xparse` for this to work (release 2017/02/10 or later).

[image]

Answer (score 7):

`hyperref` does a redefinition of `\addcontentsline`, `\label` and of sectioning commands, adding functionality for hyperlinks etc.

If your definition should not interfere with `hyperref`, it should grab the definition of `\@part` etc. after `hyperref` has done its job or redefine it after `hyperref`.

Wrapping the redefinition in a `\AtBeginDocument{...}` works.

I took the original version of the O.P. and wrapped in the `\AtBeginDocument{...}` hook, in my opinion, there's no need to use the latest version of `xparse` for this.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{spart}% makes hyperref work

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\part}{s m o}%
 {\cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{plain}%
  \if@twocolumn%
   \onecolumn%
   \@tempswatrue%
  \else%
   \@tempswafalse%
  \fi%
  \null\vfil%
 \IfNoValueTF{#3}%
  {\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\m@part*{#2}{#2}}{\m@part{#2}{#2}}}%
  {\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\m@part*{#2}{#3}}{\m@part{#2}{#3}}}}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\m@part}{s m m}%
 {\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\refstepcounter{spart}% makes hyperref work
               \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#3}}%
                {\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax%
                \refstepcounter{part}%
                \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#3}%
              \else%
                \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#3}%
              \fi}%
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering%
     \interlinepenalty \@M%
    \normalfont%
  \IfBooleanF{#1}{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax%
              \huge\bfseries \partname~\thepart%
              \par%
              \vskip 20\p@%
              \fi}%
 \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
\@endpart}
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Teil 1}
\Blinddocument
\part*{Teil 2}
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```